# If I put an extra marble in a marble-filled-pipe how fast will one drop out on the other side (and is this different from pushing a stick)?

Tags: velocity

I thought I had found the answer to the question of how fast the other end of a stick will react if I push it (I thought after reading the answers and comments that the other side of the stick reacts conform to the speed of sound in the stick). But then I thought of this. A pipe is filled with marbles. I put an extra marble in on one side. When will a marble drop out on the other side? I can't imagine that the speed of sound is involved in this. Will not another marble drop out (almost) instantaneously? If the pipe is long enough and this would happen with the speed of sound, wouldn't the pipe be momentarily too short for all the marbles to fit? Is this different from pushing a stick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you again say you cannot imagine this (I read your other question :-)), again the speed of sound is involved. Already pushing one single marble involves the sound speed in the marble... pushing one single marble does not mean that the other side from where you push moves *instantly* in sync with the side on where you push... it only moves after the perturbation traveled to the other side of the marble (the same as with a stick). This will not change if you push many marbles.

Your problem with the imagination are two things, I guess:

- The speed of sound in solids is very fast (in metals $\mathcal{O}(10^3m/s)$... think about how large the object must be for this to have a noticeable effect). This is why we think in everyday life every push results in instantaneous movement of the whole object.
- If the object does not move instantaneously, then it must somehow be compressed for a short moment of time... you may think this is not possible for solids, but actually it is.

Comment: Yeah, it's in fact exactly the same. If you put an extra marble in the pipe they can indeed become smaller. If I pushed an extra marble in with a velocity exceeding that of the speed of sound in the marble (for a small pipe) they could indeed all fit in the pipe, so I see now.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Have you thought about the velocity this corresponds to? Assuming they are glass marbles, I am pretty sure, If you would do this, something would break, some marbles, and/or the pipe. :-)

Comment: Indeed! They must be wonder marbles to survive such a push...;-)